# chmod: cannot access 'file' : No such file or directory error when the file exists

Tags: permissions, chmod

I downloaded and saved 2 files on **Linux tails live os**. I have set the appropriate permissions on those 2 files to allow them as executable. This is the command I used.

```
sudo chmod 777 home/amnesia/Desktop/file
sudo chmod 777 file
```

However, when I try to access these 2 files, both the files yield me an error as **cannot access**.

I am not sure why it isn't recognizing the file permissions correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this to:

```
sudo chmod 777 home/amnesia/Desktop/file
```

this:

```
sudo chmod 777 /home/amnesia/Desktop/file
```

you left a '/' slash

better to use will be:

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/Desktop/file
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work

Comment: @hodurrr whats the output of `echo $HOME`. tell me

Comment: what is the location of file, if you download it may be in download folder instead of Desktop

Comment: The output is /home/amnesia and the location of the file is also /home/amnesia

Comment: @hodurrr then do this `sudo chmod 777 ~/file`

Comment: I did that and I didn't get any output (no error message, nothing). Does that mean it worked?

Comment: yes it worked not error , if you give `ls -l file`, you will get `-rwx-rwx-rwx` in begning. it worked you can accept my solution